# How can I take distance data from Google maps?

Tags: c#, google-maps, location, distance

[image: Rectangle shows desired question in image]

*I am trying to create the rewarding system for GPS if user uses some of the suggested roads,then system will reward user automaticly but I need to take google maps distance variables.*

**I was wondering if i can take shown distance data and put it into variable for further calculations?**

Comment: [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) web service should be useful.